# why "java -version" is not consistent with "where java" in my command prompt?

Tags: java, windows

As shown in the title, basically why java -version is not consistent with where java in my command prompt?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have to delete the other offending entries from `PATH` and also adjust `JAVA_HOME` separately. Also, double-check the entries in the `System` section as well as the `User` section.

Comment: Your OS decides which `java` program it uses and it doesn't care what JAVA_HOME contains in order to decide that. So I don't see a inconsistency here. Like Zabuzard said, check your PATH variable instead.

Comment: [where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where) command, by default, searches folders in PATH environment variable. Refer to this: https://superuser.com/questions/867728/user-vs-system-environment-variables-do-system-variables-override-user-variabl

Comment: It is a common misconception, but Java itself does not care about `JAVA_HOME`. If you execute any given `java.exe` binary, it'll use the JVM that it's part of. I.e. if you executed `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe` then the JDK at that path will be used. `JAVA_HOME` is only used by *other* programs to locate a specific Java installation. So if you directly execute `java.exe`, then pick the one you want and execute that. Changing `JAVA_HOME` will have no effect! And if you just call `java.exe` then the first one that's found in any directory on the `PATH` will be executed.

Comment: ok i get it. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The system will search for "java" in system variable first, if it found nothing about "java", it will then search for path in user variable. In my case, since java is already exist in system variable, so my other version of java in path in user variable is ignored.